# C# Multithreading and reordering - what's going on here?

Tags: c#, multithreading, race-condition

I have the following code:

```
    public static System.Int32 i = 0;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Thread(Worker1) { IsBackground = true }.Start();
        new Thread(Worker2) { IsBackground = true }.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Running... Press enter to quit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void Worker1(object _)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var oldValue = i;
            i++;
            var newValue = i;

            if (newValue < oldValue)
                Console.WriteLine("{2}, i++ went backwards! oldValue={0}, newValue={1}!", oldValue, newValue, DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:MM:ss.fff"));
        }
    }

    static void Worker2(object _)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            i++;
        }
    }
```

When run, this produces output that looks like this:

```
17:08:17.020, i++ went backwards! oldValue=6124653, newValue=6113984!
17:08:17.057, i++ went backwards! oldValue=18764535, newValue=18752368!
17:08:17.086, i++ went backwards! oldValue=27236177, newValue=27236176!
17:08:17.087, i++ went backwards! oldValue=27550457, newValue=27535008!
17:08:17.130, i++ went backwards! oldValue=40251349, newValue=40235492!
17:08:17.137, i++ went backwards! oldValue=42339974, newValue=42323786!
17:08:17.142, i++ went backwards! oldValue=43828602, newValue=43828436!
17:08:17.149, i++ went backwards! oldValue=45969702, newValue=45959111!
17:08:17.158, i++ went backwards! oldValue=48705847, newValue=48705549!
17:08:17.230, i++ went backwards! oldValue=71199684, newValue=71199674!
```

Note: this is being run on a quad-core i7 with hyperthreading on windows 7

As far as I can tell, either:

- Thread2 is incrementing i approx 4 billion times (but not quite!) in between the reads of oldValue and newValue. Given the numbers and timings above though, it seems like there is a higher chance of me winning the lottery 10 times in the next 2 seconds.
- The CPU and compiler are doing some reordering... This seems the logical explanation, but I can't quite figure out a sequence of operations that could actually cause this?

Can anyone shed some light on it?

---

To clarify the question: I am deliberately looking for code which reproduces memory reordering bugs as part of an educational excercise. There are many ways to fix this, I was mainly interested in analyzing what was happening.

@Tymek has shown the (blindingly obvious now that it's pointed out) answer below.

Comment: It just might happen, that the OS needs some ressources while executing your program, which lead to a the feeling that there is a reordering. Just expect that with multithreading and multiple unsynschronized operations, every possible permutation will happen - sooner or later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You surely know that i++ is not atomic and looks really like something like this:

- read `i` from memory to a register,
- increment the register,
- write register to memory where `i` is,
- return `i`;

This sequence can be interrupted at any stage.

Having this in mind, one case which generates your message of doom is a follows:

- Let's `i` be `100`;
- Thread 2 reads `100` and is interrupted;
- Thread 1 executes for a while and increments i to 120 (few full loops), then reads `i` as `120`, reads `i` and increments it to `121` and is interrupted before `var newValue = i;`;
- Thread 2 increments `i` to `101` and is interrupted;
- Thread one runs and executes `var newValue = i` <- this will read in `101`;

Now `oldValue` is `120` and `newValue` is `101`.

Answer (score 1):

If u want that the assignment of the old-value, the incrementation of i and the assignment of the new-value happens "at the same time" u should use a lock.
Just introduce a private variable and then use the lock on this. This looks something like:

```
lock(lockObj)
{
  var oldValue = i;             
  i++;             
  var newValue = i;
}
```

Comment: You would have to lock, both i++ statements in the provided code. Locking just one will not change much.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this issue you could use [Interlocked.Increment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd78zt0c.aspx) it will garantee that operation will be atomic and thread safe. When you use i++ it is not atomary and value of it could be changed during incrementation (from another thread e.g.).